# Issues with changing size on Sketchpad project

Tags: javascript, css

I am doing The Odin Project exercises and so far I am doing the Etch-a-Sketch project, it's almost finished except for one little issue. Every time I click the button to set a size the board will shrink and sometimes, the click won't work. My goal is to change the size and replace the older one, I think it might be stacking, but Im not sure.

Thank you.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color]');
let buttonSize = document.querySelector('.get-size');
let buttonClear = document.querySelector('.clear');
let color = 'black';
let click = true;
let clickMessage = document.querySelector('.click-message-on');
let clickMessageOff = document.querySelector('.click-message-off');
let errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error-message');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function changeColor(){
        let colorSelection = button.dataset.color;
        color = colorSelection;
    })
})

buttonSize.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let size = getSize();
    getBoard(size, size);
});

buttonClear.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.sq');
    squares.forEach((square) => {
        square.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(235, 135, 99)';
    })
})

function getBoard(cols, rows) {
    let board = document.querySelector('.board');
    board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${cols}, 1fr)`
    board.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${rows}, 1fr)`
    let size = cols * rows;
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        let fill = document.createElement('div');
        fill.className = 'sq';
        fill.addEventListener('mouseover', getColor);
        board.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', fill);
    }
    board.addEventListener('click', function() {
        click = !click;
        if (click) {
            clickMessage.textContent = 'Click enabled, you can paint! ✔️';
            clickMessageOff.textContent = '';
        } else {
            clickMessageOff.textContent = 'Click disabled, you can\'t paint! ❌';
            clickMessage.textContent = '';
        }
    })
}

function getColor() {
    if (click) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = color;
        if (color === 'random') {
        this.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%)`;
        }
    }
}

function getSize() {
    let input = prompt('Select a size');
    input = parseFloat(input);
    if (input <= 0) {
        errorMessage.textContent = 'Negative numbers are not valid!';
    } else if (input > 64) {
        errorMessage.textContent = 'Enter a number between 1 and 64';
    } else if (input !== Number(input)) {
        errorMessage.textContent = 'Only numbers allowed';
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}

getBoard(32, 32);
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container-size {
    display: flex;
}

.board {
    display: grid;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid orangered;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.sq {
    background: rgb(235, 135, 99);
    border: thin solid rgb(230, 102, 55);
}

.space {
    margin-left: 3em;
}

.get-size {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.click-message-on, .click-message-off {
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

.click-message-off {
    color: red
}

.error-message {
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Sketchpad!</title>
    <h1>Sketchpad!</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-size">
            <button class="btn btn-warning get-size">Select a size</button>
        </div>
        <div class="click-message-on">Click enabled, you can paint! ✔️</div>
        <div class="click-message-off"></div>
        <div class="error-message"></div>
        <div class="board"></div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button data-color="black" class="btn btn-dark">Black</button>
            <button data-color="red" class="btn btn-danger">Red</button>
            <button data-color="blue" class="btn btn-primary">Blue</button>
            <button data-color="random" class="btn btn-success">Random</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary clear space">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</head>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new nodes without removing the previous ones. You can fix this by first removing all child nodes in board using `board.removeChild` in your `getBoard` function.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color]');
let buttonSize = document.querySelector('.get-size');
let buttonClear = document.querySelector('.clear');
let color = 'black';
let click = true;
let clickMessage = document.querySelector('.click-message-on');
let clickMessageOff = document.querySelector('.click-message-off');
let errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error-message');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function changeColor() {
    let colorSelection = button.dataset.color;
    color = colorSelection;
  })
})

buttonSize.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let size = getSize();
  getBoard(size, size);
});

buttonClear.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.sq');
  squares.forEach((square) => {
    square.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(235, 135, 99)';
  })
})

function getBoard(cols, rows) {
  let board = document.querySelector('.board');
  
  // This removes the child nodes
  while (board.lastChild) {
    board.removeChild(board.lastChild);
  }

  board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${cols}, 1fr)`
  board.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${rows}, 1fr)`
  let size = cols * rows;
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    let fill = document.createElement('div');
    fill.className = 'sq';
    fill.addEventListener('mouseover', getColor);
    board.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', fill);
  }
  board.addEventListener('click', function() {
    click = !click;
    if (click) {
      clickMessage.textContent = 'Click enabled, you can paint! ✔️';
      clickMessageOff.textContent = '';
    } else {
      clickMessageOff.textContent = 'Click disabled, you can\'t paint! ❌';
      clickMessage.textContent = '';
    }
  })
}

function getColor() {
  if (click) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = color;
    if (color === 'random') {
      this.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%)`;
    }
  }
}

function getSize() {
  let input = prompt('Select a size');
  input = parseFloat(input);
  if (input <= 0) {
    errorMessage.textContent = 'Negative numbers are not valid!';
  } else if (input > 64) {
    errorMessage.textContent = 'Enter a number between 1 and 64';
  } else if (input !== Number(input)) {
    errorMessage.textContent = 'Only numbers allowed';
  } else {
    return input;
  }
}

getBoard(32, 32);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-size {
  display: flex;
}

.board {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid orangered;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.sq {
  background: rgb(235, 135, 99);
  border: thin solid rgb(230, 102, 55);
}

.space {
  margin-left: 3em;
}

.get-size {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.click-message-on,
.click-message-off {
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

.click-message-off {
  color: red
}

.error-message {
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>Sketchpad!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Sketchpad!</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-size">
      <button class="btn btn-warning get-size">Select a size</button>
    </div>
    <div class="click-message-on">Click enabled, you can paint! ✔️</div>
    <div class="click-message-off"></div>
    <div class="error-message"></div>
    <div class="board"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button data-color="black" class="btn btn-dark">Black</button>
      <button data-color="red" class="btn btn-danger">Red</button>
      <button data-color="blue" class="btn btn-primary">Blue</button>
      <button data-color="random" class="btn btn-success">Random</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary clear space">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but it doesn't work, it throws me a ReferenceError, lastChild is not defined at getBoard.

And another thing I found out is that removing the border property  (width, style and color) from CSS or JS will wotk just fine and you will be able to change size without problems. I removed .sq CSS property and worked fine, what is the reason for such behaviour? I would like to add a thin border just like I did but seems incompatible.
And about the solution you gave me... am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: @Quickpois0n I don't know why you are getting the error. I have updated the answer with the entire working solution you can check out. As for removing the `.sq` class, I don't think it will solve the problem just hides it. You can open the inspector and see whether the previous dom nodes are being removed or not.

Comment: Ah, yeah, its working, I dont know why it didnt work for me. Now it works, thanks. I have seen a few videos about this project and noone uses this method to change the size but even tho it works for them. I know is a really simply question but hows the explanation for the while fix? while the lastChild of .board exists (its true) then it removes it from the board? Im very new on JS and would like to fully understand why this happens before using it. Thank you.

Comment: @Quickpois0n There can be plenty of other ways to do this, like you can remove the whole `.board` element and create a new one every time you change its size. The `lastChild` property returns a reference to the last child element or `null` if there are no child elements. So the while loop checks for last child and then removes it using `removeChild` method passing that reference as a parameter, until there are no more child elements.

Comment: All creal now, thank you very much for your time. Very helpful.